# is there any way to compile DataStage 11.7 jobs in Unix/Linux using shell?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, datastage

I have tried using dsjob --help if there are any compiling commands but I cannot seem to find any command which can compile. is it possible to compile using uvsh because there isnt much material i can find regarding that either so any links related to that would be helpful thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can compile jobs with `dscc` command. The `dsjob` command is intended to control jobs, not to compile them.

See:
[dscc](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iis/11.3?topic=jobs-compile-from-client-command-line)
[dsjob](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iis/11.7?topic=interface-commands-controlling-infosphere-datastage-jobs)

Comment: dscc command is only available on Window CMD right? or am I missing something?
was not able to find dscc in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [IBM DataStage Flow Designer REST API](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iis/11.7?topic=designer-rest-api#compile) to compile jobs. Since it's pure REST, there is no need for a client tier (like there is when using dscc). So you can write a script/program which also runs on the services tier.